# How to access saved Data from the FormFLow in the same method

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, formflow

I have been trying to learn how bots work using several tutorials.

[This blog post](http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/8/Introduction-To-FormFlow-With-The-Microsoft-Bot-Framework) is very handy when explaining formflows, however when it comes to saving the data I have a question with the project I am trying to do.

The way he handles it is saving the data in the .OnCompletion as seen below:

```
public static IForm<ProfileForm> BuildForm()
{
    return new FormBuilder<ProfileForm>()
            .Message("Welcome to the profile bot!")
            .OnCompletion(async (context, profileForm) =>
            {
                // Set BotUserData
                context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<bool>(
                    "ProfileComplete", true);
                context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<string>(
                    "FirstName", profileForm.FirstName);
                context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<string>(
                    "LastName", profileForm.LastName);
                context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<string>(
                    "Gender", profileForm.Gender.ToString());
                // Tell the user that the form is complete
                await context.PostAsync("Your profile is complete.");
            })
            .Build();
}
```

However the way he accesses the variables set is in the Message Controller using:

```
// Get any saved values
        StateClient sc = activity.GetStateClient();
        BotData userData = sc.BotState.GetPrivateConversationData(
            activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id, activity.From.Id);
        var boolProfileComplete = userData.GetProperty<bool>("ProfileComplete");
        if (!boolProfileComplete)
        {
            // Call our FormFlow by calling MakeRootDialog
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, MakeRootDialog);
        }
        else
        {
            // Get the saved profile values
            var FirstName = userData.GetProperty<string>("FirstName");
            var LastName = userData.GetProperty<string>("LastName");
            var Gender = userData.GetProperty<string>("Gender");
```

Is there anyway to do this inside the same class as the formflow? I am trying to use it as a comparison to guide the ongoing conversation:

```
 public IForm<DVLADialog> BuildForm()
    {

        OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<DVLADialog> completeForm = async(context, state) =>
        {

            try
            {                    
                if (dvla.AbiGroupOneToFifty <= 30 && Value <= 50000)
                {
                    await context.PostAsync($"Success!.");
                }
                else
                {
                    await context.PostAsync("Uh Oh");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }

        };

        return new FormBuilder<DVLADialog>()
            .Field(nameof(Value))
            .Field(nameof(DateOfPurchase))
            .Field(nameof(Modifications))
            .Field(nameof(Stored))
            .Field(nameof(Postcode))
            .Confirm("Is this all correct? {*}")
            .OnCompletion(async (context, save) =>
            {
                // Set BotUserData
                context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<bool>(
                    "ProfileComplete", true);
                context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<float>(
                    "Value", save.Value);
                context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<DateTime>(
                    "Date Of Purchase", save.DateOfPurchase);
                context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<string>(
                    "Mods", save.Modifications.ToString());
                context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<string>(
                    "Stored", save.Stored.ToString());
                context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<string>(
                    "Postcode", save.Postcode.ToString());

                // Tell the user that the form is complete
                await context.PostAsync("Your profile is complete.");
            })
            .OnCompletion(completeForm)
            .Build();
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Why don't you simply add your test in `.OnCompletion(async (context, save) => ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the correct method. A lot of the information I read online said that FormFlows do not save the user input. It is saved in the state. e.g. state.Value. So the code:

```
public IForm<DVLADialog> BuildForm()
    {

        OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<DVLADialog> completeForm = async(context, state) =>
        {

            try
            {                   

                if (dvla.AbiGroupOneToFifty <= 30 && state.Value <= 50000)
                {
                    await context.PostAsync($"Yay");
                }
                else
                {
                    await context.PostAsync("Uh Oh");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }

        };

        return new FormBuilder<DVLADialog>()
            .Field(nameof(Value))
            .Field(nameof(DateOfPurchase))
            .Field(nameof(Modifications))
            .Field(nameof(Stored))
            .Field(nameof(Postcode))
            .Confirm("Is this all correct? {*}")

            .OnCompletion(completeForm)
            .Build();
    }
}
```

Problem was much easier to fix than I thought. Hope this helps someone in the future.